# Переопределение методов в классе

Tags: java, методы, интерфейс, переопределение

У меня есть следующее задание по учебе:

Класс `AsciiCharSequence` должен:

1. Реализовывать интерфейс `java.lang.CharSequence`.
2. Иметь конструктор, принимающий массив байт.
3. Определять методы `length()`, `charAt()`, `subSequence()` и `toString()`.

Я вроде бы сделал, что нужно, но возникают следующие проблемы:

1. Игнорируется метод `toString()`
2. *Cannot resolve method `charAt(int)`*
3. *Cannot resolve method `subSequence(int, int)`*

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] example = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33};
        AsciiCharSequence answer = new AsciiCharSequence(example);
        System.out.println("Последовательность - " + answer.toString());//Hello!
        System.out.println("Размер её - " + answer.length());//6
        System.out.println("Символ под № 1 - " + answer.charAt(1));//e
        System.out.println("Подпоследовательность - " +  answer.subSequence(1, 5));//ello

        //проверка на нарушение инкапсуляции private поля
        System.out.println(answer.toString());//Hello!
        example[0] = 74;
        System.out.println(answer.toString());//Hello!
    }

    public interface CharSequence {

        int length();

        char charAt(int s);

        int subSequence(int start, int end);
    }

    public static class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        public byte[] b1;
        public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] bytes) {
            b1 = bytes;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(b1);
        }
        public int subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return b1.subSequence(start, end);
        }
        @Override
        public int length() {
            return b1.length;
        }
        @Override
        public char charAt(int s) {
            return b1.charAt(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, интерфейс [`java.lang.CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) и приведённый в коде интерфейс различаются.  В частности, метод `CharSequence::subSequence` должен возвращать не целое число, как в представленном коде, а [другую последовательность символов `CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#subSequence-int-int-):

> `CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end)`
> Returns a `CharSequence` that is a subsequence of this sequence...

Отдельная проблема в том, что поле `b1` в указанной реализации почему-то объявлено с общим доступом (public), что явно нарушает инкапсуляцию, и непонятно, почему после изменения содержимого массива `example[0] = 74;` ожидается вывод *старой строки* `"Hello!"`, тогда как получится `"Jello!"`.

Во-вторых, реализация метода `toString` при помощи [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-byte:A-) выведет содержимое массива в числовом виде (`[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33]`), тогда как по тесту *явно предполагается*, что требуется получить обычную строку, что легко выполнить при помощи конструктора [`new String(byte[] bytes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-).

В-третьих, для массива байтов `b1` НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНЫ методы `subSequence` и `charAt`, соответственно, возникают ошибки компиляции `Cannot resolve method '%method_signature%'`:

- `CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end)`:
  Для получения подпоследовательности можно использовать метод [`Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[] bytes, int from, int to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-), чтобы создать новый экземпляр `AsciiCharSequence`.
- `char charAt(int index)`
  Для получения *символа* из данного массива байтов достаточно обратиться к элементу массива по индексу, но при этом потребуется явное приведение полученного *байта* к `char`.

Информации, приведённой в ответе, вполне достаточно для *самостоятельной реализации* класса `AsciiCharSequence`, который имплементирует *стандартный интерфейс `java.lang.CharSequence`*.